# Laravel queue worker is not registering service providers

Tags: laravel, queue, multi-tenant, worker

I have a package that helps to control job processing. It uses model with hyn/multi-tenant.
When running Job it throws exception `Database connection [tenant] not configured.`

It throws error only when i connect package by composer require. If i try to connect package using psr-4 autoload everything works fine!

I assume that queue worker isn't connecting Service Providers as needed.

Here is the part where exception is thrown

```php
public function getProcess($job)
{
    $job = CompositeProcessHelpers::getJob($job);

    if ($id = $this->getProcessId($job)) {
        return CompositeProcess::query()->whereKey($id)->first();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Does anybody know how laravel's queue worker registers service provider or how to solve this issue?